# Plain Report in PowerBI report similar to repeatable section in Cognos

Tags: powerbi, cognos-bi

I'm new to Power BI but am not seeing something that I feel should be pretty common report functionality.  I have a cognos report that has a list grouped by specific fields, each item in the list has fields, etc.  Each "item" is repeated in the list.

Can Power BI do something similar to this functionality?  I have been looking at multi-row cards, tables, etc. but I'm not seeing a repeater control or something that would allow to mimic this functionality?  The multi-row cards would work but I can't style them how the customer wants or needs b/c they are printed and need to match a certain format.

Even the single cards, if I could drop all the fields I need as single cards, format them how I want.  Is there a way to have all rows repeated in a "list/set" of those single cards?  Right now when I drop a bunch of single cards and a splicer it displays the first record and that is it?  Surely there is a way to get all the records.

Here is an example (I need the formatting to remain basically the same, each row from data source represents one page that looks like this)

[image]

Thanks,

Tim

Comment: Can you show an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for comment Alexis, I put up the design of the old report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible in Power BI yet. A muti-row card has similar functionality, but is not customizable enough to match what you are trying to do. Custom formatting is one of the drawbacks of Power BI at this time.

You can vote for [this idea](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/17518024-repeater-for-power-bi-charts) on the Power BI Ideas site, but I'm guessing it's not a high priority for Microsoft for now.